# Will the amplitude of a undamped forced oscillator keep increasing till infinity?

Tags: oscillators

It seems like a straightforward answer but I still need confirmation. Can someone mention diagrams as well? Because I saw that there are three possibilities depending on initial and vibrating frequency.

Comment: Why do you need confirmation of a straightforward answer? What reason have you to doubt this answer? ... What are the 3 possibilities you saw, and where did you see them?

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.cts.iitkgp.ernet.in/home/pratik/forcednew.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjoiq3TkKDWAhXGv48KHR9zDXMQFgg4MAM&usg=AFQjCNFfV8tYvUUa7RMd9Umgq2RjhsLGvg

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/355658/26969) useful - showing how you can actually generate a plot of the behavior. Just set the damping factor to zero and you will see what happens.

Comment: An answer and diagrams are given in the linked article. If you already have an answer, why are you asking here? Is there some reason you doubt that answer?

Comment: Because the article seemed too complicated than thr straightforward approach that I had in mind.

Comment: What is the straightforward approach that you had in mind?

Comment: That the amplitude will keep increasing forever/as long as the force is provided but if you see, then I have selected the answer which has something interesting in the last paragraph that I wasn'tt aware of or had never thought about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but this shouldn't surprise you.

The driving force is continually adding energy to the oscillator because it is doing work on it. But if the oscillator is undamped that energy cannot escape so it goes into continually increasing the amplitude of the oscillation. As long as the driving force is applied the amplitude of the oscillation will keep increasing.

In practice there is no such thing as a perfectly undamped oscillator so the amplitude builds up until the rate of energy loss through damping equals the rate the driving force is adding energy, then stabilises at that point.